# Windows Server Core minimised windows

Tags: windows, icons

When minimising windows on Server Core they reduce to a small bit of the title bar and get sorted into the lower left part of the screen. I believe that was the same thing that happened since Windows 95 when Explorer was not configured as shell.

Is there a way to configure Server Core to display icons instead, like pre-Explorer Windows or Windows NT? I find the title bars rather impractical since they don't show (except with the very small icon in the title bar's system menu) which program they represent and are not easily clicked without accidentally closing them or changing their window status (maximised or not maximised).

I would prefer big icons like in Windows (NT) 3.1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not a configurable change.

Note that it *did* work the exact same way even in Windows 95 once the taskbar was added. The icons were turned into mini-windows in pre-95 Chicago, then shrunk to the current size in final release. (See for example [build 34](http://www.betaarchive.com/imageupload/2012-03/1331540090.or.27549.png), [build 38](https://sites.google.com/site/chicagowin95/chic38-2.jpg), [build 40](https://sites.google.com/site/chicagowin95/chic40-33.JPG).)

There's always Alt+Tab...